# Find the length of the piece of this curve where $x \geq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, plane-curves

[image]Consider the curve C which is the intersection of the two cylinders of equations $e^z=x$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$. Find the length of the piece of this curve where $x \geq \frac{3}{2}$

I have done the parameterization, but when I apply the Length formula I am getting something that is difficult to integrate.  Also, I know that the portion of curve I am measuring is when $x \geq \frac{3}{2}$, but how do I make that in terms of 't' to get the range for my interval?  I had thought to substitute $x = \frac{3}{2}$ for my $x$ term in the parameterization, and that gives me $t=\pi/3$ and $5/pi/3$ when $x=\frac{3}{2}$  Does that seem correct and is my parameterization correct?[image]

Comment: How do those equations define 2 cylinders?

Comment: the equation e^z=x is an exponential cylinder...really it looks like an exponential plane.  Let me see if I can add a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your paper is correct, at the end you would have

$$
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\cos(t)+1}} dt.
$$

Now use

$$
\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 2 \cos^2(x) - 1,
$$

so

$$
\cos(2x) + 1 = 2 \cos^2(x),
$$

so you can write

$$
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{\cos(t/2)} dt,
$$

which is easier to solve...

$$
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{\cos(t/2)} dt =
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{\cos(t/2)}{\cos^2(t/2)} dt
= 2 \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1 - \sin^2(t/2)} d\sin(t/2)
\\= \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \left( \frac{1}{1 - \sin(t/2)} + \frac{1}{1 + \sin(t/2)} \right) d\sin(t/2)
\\= 
\Big[ \ln( 1 + \sin(t/2) ) - \ln( 1 - \sin(t/2) ) \Big]_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}
\\= 2 \ln(3)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me except for a bit strange argument with $x=3/2$ and $t=\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3$. You need to solve $x\ge 3/2$, not $=3/2$ and find the corresponding integral bounds for $t$ (btw they are missing on the picture!). Another thing: you still have to find an anti-derivative for the integrand. How do you think to proceed? Hint: find a good trigonometric formula to get rid of the root sign.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm working on with the range for the integral bounds, I'm thinking it should correspond to 3/2<=x<=2, because the x interval for the cylinder is not greater than 2, then plugging these two values of x in for the other parameters.  Gonna have to think about the anti-derivative.

Comment: $x\le 2$ is irrelevant here. $x=\cos t+1\ge 3/2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\cos t\ge 1/2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $t\in[...]$

Comment: Okay, so I'm thinking the range should be pi/3 to pi...does that sound about right?

Comment: No. Is e.g. $\cos\pi\ge 1/2$?

Comment: oh, ok, then from 5pi/3 to pi/3, the values of x there are all greater than or equal to 1/2

Comment: You should answer like $t\in[a,b]$ where the interval $[a,b]$ is correct, i.e. $a<b$.
P.S. Learn how to solve trigonometric inequalities [on the unit circle](http://www.bymath.com/studyguide/tri/sec/tri18.htm).